# Matching raw_input with JSON key value pair

Tags: python, json, unicode, match, raw-input

```
import getpass
import json

class LogInNow(object):

    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = json.load(open("password.txt"))

    def authenticate(self):
        self.username = raw_input("Enter Username> ")
        self.password = getpass.getpass("Enter Password> ")
        for k, v in self.file:
            if k == self.username and v == self.password:
                print "It worked"
            else:
                print "Fail"

go = LogInNow("password.txt")
go.authenticate()
```

A separate module uses json.dump to write both inputs into password.txt

When I:

```
>>> import login
```

I get:

```
{u'go': u'go'}
```

I read the 'u' is for unicode, is good, and must be kept.

I could concatenate the u before self.username and split the values to add the quotes, but that defeats the purpose.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add more details? Now it is not clear, what is your problem.

Comment: `for k, v in self.file:` can't be your real code. Maybe `for k, v in self.file.items():`?

Comment: Also, as a side note: `file` is a very misleading name for a dictionary; call it `passwords` or `user_dict` or something meaningful. Also, your `__init__` method takes a parameter (also named `file`) but does nothing with it, instead hardcoding `"password.txt"`. If you want to hardcode the path, don't ask the caller to pass one in; if you want the caller to pass one in, use what's passed in. If you want a default value, you can do `def __init__(self, file="password.txt")` to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: @abarnert yes that's my real code. What do you mean __init__ does nothing with parameter file, instead hardcoding "password.txt"? What are my alternatives asides from the file="password.txt" one you mentioned?

Comment: If that's your real code, then you're just unpacking each username into `k` and `v`. If any username is not exactly two characters long, you will get a `ValueError: too many values to unpack`. If you've only got `{u'go': u'go'}`, then that username `u'go'` will unpack into `u'g'` as the key and `u'o'` as the value, which is not very useful.

Comment: As for the hardcoding issue: just change that `open("password.txt")` to `open(file)` if you want to use the filename that's passed in. (As another side note, you really ought to `close` the file—or, better, use a `with` statement.)

Comment: Awesome, but why ought I close it? What's the purpose? And how is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `u` is not part of the string, any more than the quotes are. The `u'go'` is just how Python represents a Unicode string whose value is `go`. You do not need to "concatenate the u" or anything like that.

The `raw_input` will return `'go'`, rather than `u'go'`, because it's reading in an encoded byte string. But in Python 2.x, if you compare those two strings, they're still equal. Try it:

```
>>> 'go' == u'go'
True
```

So, there is no problem here.

However, as soon as you start dealing with non-ASCII usernames or passwords, then you *are* going to have a problem. You will need to call `decode` on the values you got from the user, using the input's encoding, like this:

```
>>> self.username = raw_input("Enter Username> ").decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
```

This is a bit clumsy, but hey, Unicode is clumsy in Python 2.x, that's why Python 3.x was invented.

---

There is, however, a bug in your code that may be causing whatever problem you're seeing:

```
for k, v in self.file:
```

When you loop over a dictionary, you loop over its *keys*, not its key-value pairs. So, each username will be unpacked into `k` and `v`. If you have any username that aren't exactly 2 characters long, you will get `ValueError: too many values to unpack`. But because you happen to have only one username, and it happens to be exactly 2 characters long, that `u'go'` gets unpacked into `u'g'` and `u'o'`. So, instead of comparing the username to `go` and the password to `go`, you end up comparing the username to `g` and the password to `o`, which doesn't match.

If you want to iterate over key-value pairs, use `for k, v in self.file.items():`.

---

But you usually don't want to iterate through a dict's `items` to search it either. The whole point of a dict is that you can look things up instantly. Instead of this:

```
for k, v in self.file:
    if k == self.username and v == self.password:
        print "It worked"
    else:
        print "Fail"
```

… just do this:

```
if self.password == self.file.get(self.username):
    print "It worked"
else:
    print "Fail"
```

Or, if you want to distinguish "wrong password" from "unknown user":

```
try:
    if self.password == self.file[self.username]:
        print "It worked"
    else:
        print "That's the wrong password, you evil hacker"
except KeyError:
    print "I've never heard of you"
```